# window.print() triggers Confirm Dialog Preference box

Tags: javascript

I have a new window that I open with

```
window.open()
```

In the new window I run a javascript function with the `onLoad` option in the `<body>` tag of the New window's HTML.

Within the JS associated with new window, I call `window.print()`. This causes the Confirm Dialog Preference box to open in Firefox 42.0b8.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior(the prompting of the Confirm Dialog Preference) or is it inevitable if I am calling `window.print()` from a new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same issue.  The fix is to:

1. Hit Shift+F2 - this opens the developer command line at the bottom of the browser
2. in the developer command line, type in:

   pref set dom.successive_dialog_time_limit 0

and hit enter.

This was a tough one to track down.  It's not a programmatic solution, but hope it works out for you.